# What is difference index.html vs index.jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, difference

One URL ends in 'index.html'. Another URL ends in 'index.jsp'. Explain how these two requests result in very different behavior by the server.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please just google "jsp vs html" and if required come back to this question.

Comment: For example take a look at [this](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-jsp-and-html/) please.

Comment: Homework alert. Same question from the homework, not even a personal modification.

Comment: In my opinion if someone has a question like this, the only answer is : please google your question, find a good book, tutorial,... and then come back with a better question. (No matter it's a homework or something else it's very very basic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSP is a file extension for Java Server Pages file format. Think a JSP like an HTML page containing a reference to Java servlets, or,  java server side applets.

JSP files help to deliver server side customized content on a webpage through servlets. JSP files keep the Java code secret because it runs server side.

`index.html` is the default page for that directory. On most Web servers, the default page in a directory is named "index.html". So, index.jsp would be the a default Java Server Page in a directory.

Comment: "A JSP is an HTML page", are you sure?!

Comment: Not properly, but, in this didactic context, it is enough.