# How to convert local JSP file to HTML

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP file at my local system and want to covert it to HTML through Java. 
Can you provide a reference link or tell me how to accomplish this?

Pallavi

Answer (score 1):

Jsp files are meant to serve dyanamic content.But you cant do that with `html`.

Apart from that,

- It provides support for taglibs [`jstl`](https://jstl.java.net/),[`EL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)
- You can write java codes inside it [`scriptlets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html), however it is not considered as good practice

Also have a look at here [What is difference index.html vs index.jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299237/what-is-difference-index-html-vs-index-jsp)

<sub>Sidenote : Please choose jsp to serve dyanamic content and it is not totally same as html . The only similarity is renders html content</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply ....Actually I want to remove all taglib,scripts etc from  JSP with Java code & just convert to HTML

Comment: You can simply remove your code blocks and taglibs . and also its headers and rename it to `.html` which will turn it to the html file

Comment: There are many things still needs to do like
Remove all <% %>
Remove all &
Match end block for </meta> 
remove &nbsp;
Match end block for </BR>  
Remove all namespace

Comment: Yes they make the file `jsp` :)

Comment: Do we need to parse line by line & remove these tags or have any Tool/code avilable to do that

Comment: no tools AFAIK . But a [link here might](http://grokbase.com/t/struts/user/041rncx4j0/convert-jsp-to-static-html) help you

Answer (score 0):

That's normally the job of a servlet container. Of course, you can do it "by hand" and you should if it is the only time you will ever need to do that.

But you can also install a tomcat on your local machine. It comes with defaults web applications. You can just put the jsp in one of the default apps (or in one of yours if you have), get it from a browser and save the HTML file. It is much more work but it may worth it if :

- you have to do that on multiple JSP
- you want to be sure of how a Java EE or servlet container would translate the file
- you considere to later do Jave EE programming

Comment: Hi I am not making connection . I am using JSP as a file & want to do file manipulation to convert to HTML file locally

Comment: You cannot hope to find a tool that does it automagically. What do you want to do with `@include`, with `<jsp:include`>, with `<c:if>`, `c:foreach>`, `<c:set>`, <jsp:useBean>, ... The only foolproof ways are *manually* in a text editor (choose your own) or full processing via a servlet container.

Comment: Actually I want to parse jsp file with DOM parser. As it is not possible to parse jsp , I want to convert it to HTML

Comment: @user3652391 If JSP was to produce XHTML, it should be valid XML (apart from `@` meta) and a DOM parser should process it.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use the features of JSP,you can delete some link such as start with "<% ...>" and change ***.jsp into ***.html.And add this tag at the top 
WARNING: make sure you don't use the jsp servlet or other features,otherwise please don't do that.

Comment: "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Answer (score 0):

You can change `.jsp` to `.html` and replace `<%= variable %>` with `{{ variable }}`.
Remove all JSP directives and tags, such as `<%@ page %>` and `<%! %>`.

Remove all Java code, including JSP scriptlets, expressions, and declarations, from the JSP file.

Save the modified file with a `.html` extension.